# JST/HJST connector identification

Tags: identification, connector, power-connector

I am trying to replace the power cable on a Yamaha RX-385 receiver; it connects to the board via this connector, which I am failing to find on Mouser/Digikey. It seems almost like a 3-pin connector with one pin removed...

(A larger version of an image will be displayed, if you "click" that image below.)

[image]

Text on the female side: "HJST d E".

[image]

Text on the male (board) side: "H JST", a raised "1" and a separate "3".

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: JST stands for "Japan Solderless Terminals".. I have had to find connectors like this one myself many many times, and it often involves looking through connectors on Mouser/Farnell/RS-Components or even DigiKey or even on google-pictures for hours and hours, not an effort I am willing to put in, in order to answer this question.. Maybe somebody else will, but my best advise to you would be to just get cracking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's either a JST [VA](https://www.jst.com/products/crimp-style-connectors-wire-to-board-type/va-connector/) or [VAJ](https://www.jst.com/products/crimp-style-connectors-wire-to-board-type/vaj-connector/) connector.

[image]

img source: https://www.jst.com/products/crimp-style-connectors-wire-to-board-type/vaj-connector/

Both of these series will mate with the same header (B2P3-VH and B2P3S-VH) so either one should work

See the datasheets for all of the part numbers for the housings and pins:

- VA datasheet: https://www.jst.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/eVA.pdf
- VAJ datasheet:
  https://www.jst.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/eVAJ.pdf

**DigiKey Links**

VAR-2 Housing (VA series): https://www.digikey.com/short/8w8m7vb5

VA crimp pin: https://www.digikey.com/short/wvjncbm0

Comment: Did you just recognize the connector? If not, how did you search for it?

Comment: I saw that JST was the manufacturer and looked through their online catalog of wire-to-board connectors: https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/search_e.php?type=1&id=1&page=1
They don't have that many different series so I just scrolled until I saw the photos that matched.